# Will mutex locking outside the thread function still lock the thread?

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

I was wondering if I have a mutex lock variable shared by multiple classes, and within a thread I call a method on an object and I lock the mutex variable within that method will it act accordingly?

I have the following header included in all files in my project so that I can use the mutex lock globally

```
#ifndef THREADS
#define THREADS
#include <pthread.h>
extern pthread_mutex_t lock;
#define lock_thread() pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
#define unlock_thread() pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
#endif
```

So within my thread function I can lock and unlock when accessing critical sections:

```
lock_thread();
user = create_user(username, password, ID++, license_num, preg, disability, vehicle_type);
unlock_thread();
```

Now after I create a user the user can access specific "Actions" that they have permissions for. Each Action is its own class with a "perform" method.

For example:

```
Action newaction;
newaction.perform(socket, user.getID);
```

I pass in the socket for the current thread and users ID since it will interact with the database. Now if I choose to perform a "lock_thread()" within a perform method will it perform similarly to locking it within the thread function itself?

Comment: If you call a function within a thread everything the function does is also within the thread. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. But if you are asking whether or not it's safe to try to lock a mutex from multiple threads then my response would be that I don't see how a mutex could be useful if you couldn't try to lock it from multiple threads.

Comment: Provide some code - to show the problem. Because taking what you are asking from the current wording -  the answers are already in comments

Comment: @Kevin yeah basically thankyou

Comment: Yes, mutexs protect against data races.  A code example could let use know if you are using it correctly.

Comment: "will it act accordingly?" ... what do you think is "accordingly" ?

Comment: I have the feeling you think code that is running within a thread you have started is different from other code. However all code is running within a thread. Only the first thread that call's your main is created for you by the OS so it can start executing your program. So yes regardless from where you call lock_thread() it will work the same.